# custom camera feed on fedora when using zoom.us

Tags: fedora, file-descriptors, camera

[zoom](https://zoom.us) work conferences became very popular lately.
I saw some of my colleagues (who have macOS) use [snap camera](https://snapcamera.snapchat.com) in zoom, so I tried looking for a goofy camera I can use as well on linux (fedora 29).
I found [hasciicam](https://github.com/jaromil/hasciicam), which looks nice.
But I have no idea how to use it inside zoom.

When I start hasciicam, I cannot use camera in zoom at all. I'm guessing there's a single camera feed that cannot be shared.

I was thinking, maybe the camera feed can be "edited" and fed back to same file descriptor zoom is trying to grab from the first place.
If so, is it possible? If not, is there another way to hack around this, so I get a custom camera in zoom?